# Always show ASP.NET TextBox tooltip

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I made script that will compare values of two ASP.NET TextBoxes:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var _t1 = $(document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>"));
           var _t2 = $(document.getElementById("<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>"));
           $(_t1).on("keyup", function () {
               if (_t1.val() == _t2.val()) {
                   $(_t1).attr('title', 'MATCH');
               }
               else {
                   $(_t1).attr('title', 'NO MATCH');
               }
           });
       });
       </script>
```

Now the result, if it matches or not, is displayed in a tooltip. Can I somehow force that tooltip to always be shown?

Comment: Put it in a label instead of a tooltip?

Comment: no, it's not possible

Comment: The reason why i wanted to use tooltip is because i have many textboxes in table and there is not much room for label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `title` tooltip is something that will be visible only when you hover your mouse on that particular element that has `title` attribute with some value and you are not performing any keyboard `key-press,up,down` etc. so if you want to show the message as long as you are tying in the any box and show either that match or doesn't match. you need to use `label` and set value in that and show label only when you are typing in t1 or t2.  check the below suggestion.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var _t1 = $('#first');
  var _t2 = $('#second');
  
  $(document).on("keyup", '#first, #second' ,
      function () {     
        if ($(_t1).val() == $(_t2).val()) {
          $('#IsMatch').html('MATCH');
        }
        else {
          $('#IsMatch').html('NO MATCH');
        }
  });
  
  //show label only if has focus on first or second textbox
  $(document).on('focus blur', '#first, #second', 
    function(){    
    if ($(_t1).is(':focus') || $(_t2).is(':focus')) {
       $('#IsMatch').fadeIn('fast');
      }
      else {      
       $('#IsMatch').fadeOut('fast');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='first'>
<br/>
<input type='text' id='second'>
<br/>
<label id='IsMatch'></label>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net, you can't override the behaviour of the tooltip. 
You can use label instead of tooltip.

In Windows Form though, you can use ToolTip.ShowAlways can be used.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.showalways(v=vs.110).aspx